# Searchbar in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I want to implement a searchbar in UIWebView, so that when the UIWebView gets called, a searchbar will appear from top and after typing and pressing Go on keyboard, the webview will automatically search in Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `thetextDidChange` method to get the text. then implement the `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` method and load a webView with the following URL:

```
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q={insert-your-text-here}
```